# Swift: How to get Console User, UID, and GID via SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I am able to get the Username, UID and GID from SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser using python:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 from SystemConfiguration import SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser
 cfuser = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser( None, None, None )
 print cfuser[0] # Returns console user, e.g.: myUsername
 print cfuser[1] # Returns console user’s UID, e.g.: 501
 print cfuser[2] # Returns console user’s GID, e.g.: 20
```

How can I get this same return using Swift?

Swift Declaration of SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser

```
 func SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(_ store: SCDynamicStore!,
                                    _ uid: CMutablePointer<uid_t>,
                                    _ gid: CMutablePointer<gid_t>) -> Unmanaged<CFString>!
```

My Swift Call

```
 var uid: CMutablePointer<uid_t>!
 var gid: CMutablePointer<gid_t>!

 var cfuser: NSArray = [SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(nil,uid,gid)]

 // the return has only one element containing the username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift function `SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser` takes a `CMutablePointer<uid_t>` argument which means that you have to pass the *address* of a `uid_t` variable.
Also you should check if the call succeeded (otherwise `nil` is returned),
and you
have to convert the returned unmanaged object as described in
[Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html):

```
import SystemConfiguration

var uid: uid_t = 0
var gid: gid_t = 0

if let theResult = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(nil, &uid, &gid) {
    let name = theResult.takeUnretainedValue()
    println("name = \(name), uid = \(uid), gid = \(gid)")
} else {
    println("failed")
}
```